# Facebook debugger is seeing code that isn't there

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-like

When Facebook debugger scrapes http://www.daisyworld.co.za it says 'Can't Download:  Could not retrieve data from URL.' When I click 'See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL', this is what I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body><p>ÿþ</p></body>
</html>
```

But what is actually there is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">  
<html>
<head>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-language" CONTENT="En">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Style-Type" CONTENT="text/css">
```

None of the other pages in the domain where I implemented a like button have any problems, it works just fine & I basically used the same pieces of fb code, for all of them with just the different particulars for each page. I cannot figure out what the problem is except that it seems that the debugger is looking at a cached file but surely that isn't supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Maria-Helena

I just hit this issue as well and discovered that facebook's scraper was appearing as a inbound JSON request. Since that particular route was set up to handle both JSON and HTML responses, FB was getting a big gnarly JSON blob instead of the actual web page. Not sure if this solves your exact problem, but hopefully sparks some fresh ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the file with a different encoding - going from unicode to UTF-8 did it for me.